# To split at whitespace in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a data of type -

```
500 3.6673656 
----------
1000 3.2707536
----------
1500 3.2356145
----------
2000 3.0495141
----------
2500 3.016674
```

i.e. time and the distance. 
I need to split time in one array and distance in an other. 
by using `my @line = split( /\s+/, $_);` i could store the distance in one array, but can't store time. 
Is there any other way to separately store each of them in different array?

input is taken from a file and contents are stored in `@array`.

my script:

```
    foreach $_ (@array){ 
    if($_ =~ /[@]/) {# do nothing, it's a comment or formatting line} 
    else  {my @line = split( /\s+/, $_);
    print "@line\n";}
}
```

Comment: Which is which? Just looks like a bunch of numbers to me.

Comment: Its - at time 500 distance is 3.6673656 and so on.

Comment: time and distance are separated by a single space.

Comment: Why are you checking if the line contains an `@` character? Are the `----------` lines part of the data?

Comment: Btw, for a first question this is pretty good. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Why not use `my ($time, $distance) = split; push @times, $time; push @distance, $distance;`? If you actually do need them in different arrays. Question is how you intend to use the data afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

Let's get all fancy pants:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @array;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    push @array, $line;
}

#
# As two separate arrays (Not so good)
#
my @times;
my @distances;
for my $entry ( @array ) {
    chomp $entry;               # Not needed, but never hurts
    next if $entry =~ /--+$/;   # Next if all dashes
    my ( $distance, $time ) = split /\s+/, $entry;
    push @times, $time;
    push @distances, $distance;
}
say "The first entry as two distinct arrays";
say "Distance: $distances[0]";
say "Time: $times[0]";

#
# As two entries in a single array
#
my @velocities;
for my $entry ( @array ) {
    chomp $entry;               # Not needed, but never hurts
    next if $entry =~ /--+$/;   # Next if all dashes
    my @velocity = split /\s+/, $entry;
    push @velocities, \@velocity;
}
say "The first entry as an array of arrays";
say "Distance: " . $velocities[0]->[0];
say "Time: " . $velocities[0]->[1];
#
# As a hash in an array (Better Still)
# Note: Using regular expression to split
#
my @velocities2;
for my $entry ( @array ) {
    chomp $entry;               # Not needed, but never hurts
    next unless $entry =~ /\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
    my %velocity;
    $velocity{DISTANCE} = $1;
    $velocity{TIME} = $2;
    push @velocities2, \%velocity;
}
say "The first entry as an array of hashes";
say "Distance: " . $velocities2[0]->{DISTANCE};
say "Time: " . $velocities2[0]->{TIME};
#
# As objects (The best!)
#
my @velocities3;
for my $entry ( @array ) {
    chomp $entry;               # Not needed, but never hurts
    next unless $entry =~ /\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
    my $distance = $1;
    my $time = $2;
    my $velocity = Local::Velocity->new( $distance, $time );
    push @velocities3, $velocity;
}
say "The first entry as an object";
say "Distance: " . $velocities3[0]->distance;
say "Time: " . $velocities3[0]->time;

package Local::Velocity;

sub new {
    my $class    = shift;
    my $distance = shift;
    my $time     = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->distance( $distance );
    $self->time( $time );
    return $self;
}

sub distance {
    my $self     = shift;
    my $distance = shift;

    if ( defined $distance ) {
        $self->{DISTANCE} = $distance;
    }
    return $self->{DISTANCE};
}

sub time {
    my $self    = shift;
    my $time    = shift;

    if ( defined $time ) {
        $self->{TIME} = $time;
    }
    return $self->{TIME};
}

package main;
__DATA__
500 3.6673656 
----------
1000 3.2707536
----------
1500 3.2356145
----------
2000 3.0495141
----------
2500 3.016674
```

The first way is what you asked: Two parallel arrays. The problem with this method is that you are now forced to keep two separate data structures in order. If you pass a time and distance, you have to pass two separate data elements. If you modify one, you have to modify the other. If you `push` or `pop` from one, you have to do it to the other.

Not too bad with just two, but imagine having to do this with a dozen or more.

The second way uses [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). References allow you to do more complex data structures. This keeps the two entries in a single array together. Now, you have one array that contains both entries. `push` one, and you `push` the other. `pop` one, and you `pop` the other. If you pass your time and distance to a subroutine, you only need to pass a single entry.

The third way takes the concept of references up a notch. Instead of using an array to store your two values, you use a hash. The advantage is that each element in the hash has a name. Is the first entry or second entry the distance? It doesn't matter, it's the entry labeled `DISTANCE`. Same advantages with an array or arrays, but now, you labeled which is which. Imagine a person with names, phones, addresses, etc., and you can see the advantage.

The final way is using [objects](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). Which as you can see are very similar to using hashes. You don't have a hash or array. You have a `Local::Velocity` object that contains a time and distance.

It seems a bit more complex, but objects have a lot of advantages:

- There's no issue whether an entry is `DISTANCE`, `Distance`, or `distance`, and there's no issue of misspelling `distanse`. You have a *method* called `distance`. Mess up the name, and your program dutifully crashes instead of continuing with bad data.
- You can modify your object without affecting your program. For example, maybe a subroutine called `velocity` that takes your object and returns the velocity. Or maybe you might want to add a direction to your velocity. Modifying the object won't affect your program.

Object oriented Perl allows you to create extremely complex data types without having to remember how you structured them. It's why most new modules are object oriented.

Answer (score 5):

Splitting lines and storing the data is trivial. How you want to store it for use later is the question. You can split the line on spaces and store it with:

```
my @data =  map { [ split ] } @lines;
```

The default call to `split`, *splits* `$_` on spaces.

Next, you can omit those lines with `'@'` with a grep:

```
my @data = map { [ split ] } grep { index( $_, '@' ) == -1 } @lines;
```

And here is just the simplest storage structure:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant TIME     => 0;
use constant DISTANCE => 1;

my @data = map { [ split ] } grep { index( $_, '@' ) == -1 } @lines;
```

Then you can address the different fields by their slot names.

```
foreach my $row ( @data ) {
    printf "At time : %d, distance was %f\n", $row->[TIME], $row->[DISTANCE];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
my (@times, @dists);
foreach (@array) { 
    if (/[@]/) {
        # do nothing, it's a comment or formatting line
    } 
    else  {
        my ($time, $dist) = split( /\s+/, $_);
        push @times, $time;
        push @dists, $dist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` command you had alright. Just save the result in two variables and `push` it into two different arrays.

```
my (@times, @distances);
foreach my $line (@array) {
  next if $line eq '----------'; # skip lines with lines (no pun intended)
  my ($t, $d) = split /\s/, $line;
  push @times, $t;
  push @distances, $d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing what you think you want to do is easy.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my (@distance, @time);

while (<DATA>) {
  next if /----/;
  chomp;

  my ($t, $d) = split; # Splits on whitespace by default
  push @distance, $d;
  push @time, $t;
}

say "@distance";
say "@time";

__DATA__
500 3.6673656 
----------
1000 3.2707536
----------
1500 3.2356145
----------
2000 3.0495141
----------
2500 3.016674
```

However, it's a really bad idea. The distance and time on each row of your input are obviously associated with each other. It's therefore a bad idea to store them in separate variables where the relationship between the two values is represented by the fact that they both have the same index in different arrays.

A far better approach would be to store the two values together (perhaps in a hash) and store those hashes (or, more accurately, references to those hashes in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my (@data);

while (<DATA>) {
  next if /----/;
  chomp;

  my %row;

  @row{qw[time distance]} = split; # Splits on whitespace by default
  push @data, \%row;
}

say Dumper \@data;

__DATA__
500 3.6673656 
----------
1000 3.2707536
----------
1500 3.2356145
----------
2000 3.0495141
----------
2500 3.016674
```

Comment: I thought of storing them in hash at first but couldn't split it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at this example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str=<<EOF;
500 3.6673656
1000 3.2707536
1500 3.2356145
2000 3.0495141
2500 3.016674
EOF

my @arr= split /\n/, $str;
my @arr1;
my @arr2;

foreach (@arr) {
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    next if ($line=~/^\s*$/);
    my ($val1,$val2) = $line=~/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
    push @arr1,$val1;
    push @arr2, $val2;
}

print Dumper (\@arr1);
print Dumper (\@arr2);
```